# String to date conversion (IST with +0530)

Tags: go

I'm not able to convert the string `"2017-12-07T20:01:33+0530"` into a date format. I'm using *RFC3339* and *RFC3339Nano* but still getting the following error:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC parsing time "2016-01-17 20:04:05 +0530": hour out of range
IST to UTC: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

This is my code:

```
IST, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

const longForm = "2006-01-02 15:04:05 +0530"
t, err := time.ParseInLocation(longForm, "2016-01-17 20:04:05 +0530", IST)
fmt.Println(t, err)
fmt.Printf("IST to UTC: %v\n\n", t.UTC())
```

Answer (score 3):

The format specifier for the timezone is wrong; you have:

```
const longForm = "2006-01-02 15:04:05 +0530"
```

But the timezone is defined as `-0700`, not `+0530`. So that should be:

```
const longForm = "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700"
```